# Getting warning about unique "key" when trying to import ReactCSSTransitionGroup into react app

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-transition-group

I hope somebody could shed some light into this issue. After many attempts, I was able to import ReactCSSTransitionGroup into my react app correctly. Now I'm getting the following warning and my transition is not working.

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

I wrapped my component in the main App.js file with the ReactCSSTransitionGroup element like this.

```
return (
  <div className="container">
    <Navigation />
        <div className="app-items-container">
            {
            this.state.notes.map((note) => {
                return(
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup {...transitionOptions}>
                        <Note noteContent={note.noteContent} 
                        noteId={note.id} 
                        key={note.id} 
                        removeNote={this.removeNote} />
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    <Form addNote={this.addNote} />
  </div>
);
```

My component already has a key passed to it. Where should I apply the key?

Comment: Is there confidence that note.id is producing unique value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want the ReactCSSTransitionGroup inside the .map function. It should be outside and ReactCSSTransitionGroup will add it's magic to each of it's children (your Note component).

It works by adding additional lifecycle methods to 'each' of it's children as they are added/removed from the DOM. So there is no need to wrap each of the Note components with ReactCSSTransitionGroup, it should simply have all the Notes as it's children.

The key warning is because ReactCSSTransitionGroup will wrap it's children in a span. When in the .map loop, react will see something like the following:

```
<span> <Note key={note.id} /> </span>
<span> <Note key={note.id} /> </span>
<span> <Note key={note.id} /> </span>
```

React will want each of the spans to have a unique key, the child Note key will be ignored.

Moving it outside the map will give you this:

```
<span> 
    <Note key={note.id} />
    <Note key={note.id} />
    <Note key={note.id} />
</span>
```

And React will be happy as each Note has a key.

Try the following:

```
return (
  <div className="container">
    <Navigation />
        <div className="app-items-container">
           <ReactCSSTransitionGroup {...transitionOptions}>
             {this.state.notes.map((note) => {
                return(
                        <Note noteContent={note.noteContent} 
                        noteId={note.id} 
                        key={note.id} 
                        removeNote={this.removeNote} />
                    )
                })
              }
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
    <Form addNote={this.addNote} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!!!. Also I found out, that after applying this solution, I could see the correct transition wrapping my note component in react inspector, but the desired effect was not working. The problem was in the CSS.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked, transition group can be tricky. If you could mark the answer as correct, it will help other people know this was a good solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

most likely you should be adding a unique key on `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup >` as well, could you try the following please?

```
return (
<div className="container">
    <Navigation />
        <div className="app-items-container">
            {
            this.state.notes.map((i, note) => {
                return(
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup key={i} {...transitionOptions}>
                        <Note noteContent={note.noteContent} 
                        noteId={note.id} 
                        key={note.id} 
                        removeNote={this.removeNote} />
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    <Form addNote={this.addNote} />
  </div>
);
```

also, what micposso said makes sense, so it would be nice if you could make sure that node.id is indeed always unique.